# KnockoutJS is only showing my template if I have an extra li

Tags: knockout.js

So I've got a template I'm using to do some recursion on some objects that may have child elements. I've got the if statement working how I want it to (I think). However, my child elements are only showing up if I have an extra li before the if statement.

Here's my template

```
<script type="text/html" id="journalTemplate">
<li data-bind="text: Description">
    <div>
    <li data-bind = "visible: IsGroup"></li>
    <!-- ko if: IsGroup -->
    <ol data-bind="template: {name: 'journalTemplate', foreach: ChildEntities}">
    </ol>
    <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</li>
```

I'm using array mapping, so there's no real view model to show, but the C# object is pretty simple: It has a Description, a bool IsGroup, and a list of ChildEntities (which is null if IsGroup is false, as a side note). If I don't have the empty li, the comment blocks of the if statement don't even show up.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not quite following. The template above works? or you need another LI element before the KO if statement for it to work? Currently your markup above is invalid. You can't have an LI element inside a div.

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle of your issue.

Comment: @madcapnmckay: Right now it works, but has that <li data-bind = "visible: IsGroup"></li> when I don't actually want that li there. I just want the li with the text and the sub ol. (I've removed the div, I just added that hoping it would fix my woes, but it didn't). I'm not sure how to put up a jsfiddle, because I'm populating my js objects from actual data in my database. I'll start working on mocking some stuff up, though.

Comment: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/7vnJ9/1/) a js fiddle. It looks correct in the fiddle because it's not displaying the empty li. I don't want the empty li to be there, though. Without the empty li, though, it doesn't properly run the template on the child items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I see the issue.  The problem is your text binding on your LI.

Text in html is represented by textNode dom elements which although they can't be written explicitly in html markup, they behave the same way. Effectively your text binding is replacing the innerHtml of your LI with whatever text it has.

What I'm less clear on is why your extra invalid LI element stops the total replacement of the innerHtml...

Anyway the correct solution is to structure your template like this.

```
<script type="text/html" id="journalTemplate">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: Description"></span>
        <!-- ko if: IsGroup -->
        <ol data-bind="template: {name: 'journalTemplate', 
                  foreach: ChildEntities}">
        </ol>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </li>
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/F2vSW/1/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I figured that out just before you posted. Don't know why the extra li thing fixed it, though. Anyway, thanks!